# Is explicitly calling base()  in derived constructors optional?

Tags: c#, .net

All the code examples always use base() as follows

```
class A 
{ 
    public A() 
    {
        Console.Writeline("A");
    } 
}

class B : A 
{ 
    public B():base() {} 
}
```

e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

whereas as i discovered recently

```
class A 
{ 
    public A()
    {
        Console.Writeline("A");
    } 
}

class B : A 
{ 
    public B() {} 
}
```

also prints A

Q - is it a new "feature" or is it bad form not to call base() in derived class constructors and will add to my bad karma and cause problems later ?

or

can calling base() safely be ignored?

Comment: the link provided is for Visual Studio 2003(so no it isn't new) and includes instructions on when to call the base constructor.  Any answer here is just going to be repeating information in the MSDN.

Comment: @cadrell0 the link has example of calling base() from derived.Constructor(), it does not answer the Q above AFAIK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No that's not new - if you do not explicitly call a base constructor, the default constructor will be called by default.

Adding this yourself I would consider just "noise", the compiler will do it for you already so you don't have to. You should only call a base constructor if you need a specific overload other than the default constructor (that means you do need to have a base constructor call though if the base class does not provide a default constructor).

Comment: To elaborate on what is meant by "the default constructor will be called", please see http://ideone.com/o26u1 (Note calling `new B("b2")` calls `B::B(String)` then `A::A()` constructor.) However, `C::C(String)` calls the `A::A(String)` constructor because of the `base(arg)` reference.

Answer (score 6):

You only need to use base if

1) You need to pass variables down to the base constructor.

2) You need to specify which base constructor to use.

Other than that you can safely leave it out. The default base constructor will be called.

Answer (score 3):

The default constructor will get called whether or not you explicitly call it with `: base()`. It's a matter of style, but the prevailing convention is to leave it off unless you're calling a specific, parameterized base constructor.

Answer (score 1):

calling base() is not required. Default base constructors are called automatically unless you explicitly call another one. It's a matter of personal preference i think, kinda like prepending `this` before accessing instance fields.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call base() from your constructor when both the parent and the child have a implicit or explicit parameterless constructor.  That will happen by default, and no, it's not new.  Typically, you would use the base() method to say which parent constructor you are calling and to pass arguments from the child's constructor to the parent's.

Try it with arguments in your constructor to see how it works.